# <flutter> does flutter have any function which can change the value of HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, flutter

I want to change value of web html element.

for example, web HTML element is like this.

```
<dd>
    <a nocr="" onclick="goOtherTCR(this, 'a=nco_x2v*4.day&amp;r=1&amp;i=1800009E_000000000000');return false;" href="#" class="_btn_time _text">00.00(Mon)Today</a>     <--- point1


    <ul>
         <li class '_i on' data-value='2022-00-00'>     
               <a onclick="return goOtherCR(this,&quot;a=nco_x2v*4&amp;r=1&amp;i=&quot;+urlencode(&quot;1800009E_000000DA154F&quot;)+&quot;&amp;u=&quot;+urlencode(this.href));" href="#">00.00(mon)Today</a>
         </li>
      
         <li> class '_i' data-value = '2022-00-01'>
                <a onclick="return goOtherCR(this,&quot;a=nco_x2v*4&amp;r=1&amp;i=&quot;+urlencode(&quot;1800009E_000000DA154F&quot;)+&quot;&amp;u=&quot;+urlencode(this.href));" href="#">00.01(Tue)</a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</dd>
```

```dart
<my code> has nothing...

Future<List<MvTime>> getData() async {
try {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
    //"Accept": "application/json",
    //"Access-Control_Allow_Origin": "*"
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    });
    final body = response.body;
    final hhtml = parse(body);

    <here is the point that i want to write code to change web html element value>

}
)
```

if i click the date(04.28) in web, point 1's( ->  where class value is '_btn_time _text')  text value changes to today's date to 04.28 and the code class value which one has same date(data-value) changes to '_i' to '_i on'.

I want to change the date by using flutter.

But I can't find the function to change HTML value by using flutter.(In js, somebody tell me that if i use 'element.classList', i can change the HTML value.)

is there any way to change the value of HTML Element by using flutter?

Comment: Its better if you provide code what you have done what you exactly want to do. Because may be there is different way of doing something that you want. Because flutter is just not about web it about other platforms too.

Comment: Also, asking for the Dart equivalent of some JavaScript API without explaining what that JavaScript API does essentially restricts your answers to people who are fluent in both languages.

Comment: i'm really sorry. i'll write my question again.

Comment: I change my question..  But i don't know this is enough.. if my question is still lack, i'll add something more again. plz give me some advise. thank u for reading.

Comment: Hi, you can try to do it with this package: https://pub.dev/packages/html . Pack description is "APIs for parsing and manipulating HTML content outside the browser."